# Как обновить кучу сайтов разом?

Tags: php

Есть много сайтов на одном сервере. Все на php (причем по большей части на голом php без фреймворков - они очень старые), но неизвестно какой версии. В смысле непонятно что у них сломается (и сломается ли вообще) если обновить php до 7 версии (сейчас 5.6). Как можно это проверить если у них нет тестов? Тупо обновиться и ждать пока ошибки посыплются? :D

Уж очень хочется обновить php. Сил больше нет на 5.6 новые проекты писать. :( Слышал правда что можно как-то сразу несколько версий php на сервере держать, но пока тоже не знаю как это сделать...

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/migration70.php шерстите код ;)

Comment: Никак, наверно, даже с тестами что-нибудь может быть упущено

Comment: @Visman нет, это не возможно. Сайтов около сотни, а разработчиков двое нас. Не вариант проверять все вручную (да и некогда).

Comment: Но зачем на 5.6 новые проекты писать? Вроде бы не должно быть великой проблемы поставить две версии php одновременно (за дебиан и прочие не скажу, но у меня на арче именно два php и стоят)

Comment: @andreymal Я просто не знаю как это делать. :( Сервер на CentOS 6.

Comment: Зачем вручную? Поиск по функциям, которые удалены и у старели в 7 версии по всем файлам на сервере.

Comment: @Visman боюсь что все не так просто. Там и синтаксис менялся и какие-то функции удалены без аналогов, а значит надо переписывать...

Comment: @DarkByte значит в первую очередь нужно поставить виртуальную машину, воткнуть туда CentOS 7, настроить деплой всей сотни сайтов в неё через Ansible и выкатить все эти достижения на боевой сервер — в общем, привести то, что есть сейчас, в порядок, а про php 7 уже потом)

Comment: @andreymal все сложнее чем кажется. :D У меня очень сильно не сложились отношения с виртуализацией... Пытался и с вагрантом и с докером, но все бестолку. Не девопс я... К тому же у этих сайтов пользовательские файлы (загружаемые) лежат прямо в папках сайтов, из-за этого весь сервер весит около терабайта. Файлов - очень много. Была идея сделать какой-то отдельный файловый сервер и вынести их туда, но пока некогда...

Comment: @DarkByte я не ту виртуализацию имею в виду — тупо центось в виртуалбоксе, чтобы обкатать все эксперименты не на боевом сервере и ничего не сломать) А с терабайтом, наверно, надо что-то делать: не знаю, что как там устроено, но, подозреваю, сервер так вечность не протянет, и лучше заранее подготовиться к каким-нибудь переделкам, чем потом второпях переделывать всё, когда всё сломается под собственным весом)

Comment: @andreymal не вы же сказали про ansible, а у меня сложилось впечатление что это что-то вроде докера, разве нет? Или надстройка над докером... Ну короче что-то в этом роде.

Comment: @DarkByte Не, это ближе к простой автоматизации выполнения команд в консоли с декларативным сахарком, надстройка над ssh. Грамотно написанные плейбуки дают удобство, предсказуемость и повторяемость окружения даже без контейнеров, несмотря на то, что на низком уровне это просто команды и python-скрипты, запускающиеся на сервере по ssh) [Но что-то это я уже в оффтопик загнул, продолжать здесь, наверное, не стоит]